# Get records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I need to join records from three tables in postgresql.

Tables structures:

**Users**

```
Residence_id | Name | Mobile

1234         | A    | 9876
23456        | B    | 9786
```

**Accounts**

```
Residence_id | Balance

1234         | 1000
4545         | 567
```

**Address**

```
Residence_id | City   | Country

1234         | Mumbai | India
0124         | London | UK
```

**Expected Results:**

```
Residence_id | Name | Mobile | Balance | City   | Country

1234         | A    | 9876   | 1000    | Mumbai | India
23456        | B    | 9786   |         |        |
4545         |      |        | 567     |        |
0124         |      |        |         | London | UK
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to set up a residence table, with all residence_ids:

```
residence_id(PK):
1234
23456
4545
0124
```

This column can be used as a constraint (foreign key) in your other 3 tables. To get your result you'll want to query this table, and join to your other 3 tables.  Something like this should work:

```
 SELECT residence.residence_id, users.name, users.mobile, accounts.balance, address.city, address.country 
  FROM residence LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON residence.residence_id=users.residence_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts ON residence.residence_id=accounts.residence_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN address ON residence.residence_id=address.residence_id
```